# How to execute a void method automatically when a breakpoint is hit?

Tags: java, android, debugging, intellij-idea, java-7

I'm using latest IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 16 EAP. I have some code in a library that initializes an object with some setters:

```
X createSomething() {
    X x = new X();
    x.setY(z);
    return x; // breakpoint on this line
}
```

I'm looking to modify this returned value's state from the debugger: calling `x.setY(y)`. I tried with conditions, because I want it to happen on every hit of the breakpointstopping at the breakpoint and using the "Evaluate Expression" window is unfeasible.

It's not possible to do this in any of the normal object oriented ways (e.g. overriding that method), nor it is possible to capture the result outside the method and modify it there because it's deep within many calls.

Here are my tries that all failed due to no support for those language features in the debugger. They failed with a dialog asking "Would you like to stop at the breakpoint?". The language level is fixed at Java 6-7 because I'm developing for Android.

#### Try 1: Call the method

> Problem processing VM event:
>   Breakpoint: 'Line 9 in `ClassName.createSomething()` (package)'
>   Error: Failed to evaluate breakpoint condition '`x.setY(y)`'
>   Reason: Boolean value expected

Also tried variants like: `x.setY(y); false;`, but it needs to be an expression.

#### Try 2: Call the method using lambda

> Problem processing VM event:
>   Breakpoint: 'Line 9 in `ClassName.createSomething()` (package)'
>   Error: Failed to evaluate breakpoint condition '`() -> { x.setY(y); return false; }`'
>   Reason: Lambdas evaluation is not supported

#### Try 3: Call the method to have a boolean expression

> Problem processing VM event:
>   Breakpoint: 'Line 9 in `ClassName.createSomething()` (package)'
>   Error: Failed to evaluate breakpoint condition '`new java.util.concurrent.Callable<Boolean>() { @Override public Boolean call() { x.setY(y); return false; } }.call()`'
>   Reason: Anonymous class evaluation is not supported

#### Try 4: Call a static method (working workaround)

I found a workaround that I want to share, but **I'm still looking for a better solution if anyone knows one: that doesn't require recompiling and restarting.**

1. Create a method in a class:

   ```
   public class SomeClass {
       public static boolean fixX(X x) {
           x.setY(y);
           return false; // don't actually stop on the breakpoint
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the breakpoint condition add

   ```
   full.pkg.SomeClass.fixX(x)
   ```

This works, but any time you want to modify the condition you'll have to restart the app. Parametrized `fixX(x, changeAbleY)` is a solution to that.

*Make sure to disable or remove the breakpoint to prevent headaches by modified behavior when debugging unrelated issues.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps:

1. Right click on the breakpoint
2. A tool popup will open, in that popup click on "More" link at the bottom then a window will open.
3. Now check "Log evaluated expression" checkbox in that window and enter your method call in the given text box e.g methodName().
4. Click OK and start debugging.
5. When the breakpoint will hit your method will get called before that line's execution.

Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-breakpoints.html

Screenshot: [Screenshot of breakpoint configuration window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivsb1.png)

IntelliJ has a feature to add "Watches" where you can execute your void method but that's manual, not automatic.

Comment: Awesome, nice post anonymous user!

Comment: It's also worth unticking the "Suspend All" checkbox or add a condition that's always "false" so the breakpoint hit doesn't stop the execution.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Thanks, just started helping others after getting too much help from others during study.

Comment: This will print "void" on each execution. An alternative is call the function on "condition" field. The expression should be; "{ methodToCall(); return false; }" (if you want stopt execution on that breakpoint, you should replace for "return true").